# How to draw fully packed loops on medial lattice?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

I want to draw a variant of the following figure, 
[image]

[Figure 22 of Freedman et al, Annals of Physics,310(2):428–492, April 2004.]

The lattice and dashed lines are easy. Using two for loops

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5]
\foreach \x in {0,...,6}{
  \foreach \y in {0,...,4}{
    \fill[black] (\x,\y) circle (0.08/1.5);
  }
}
\draw[dashed] (0,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2)--++(4,0);
\draw[dashed] (2,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get

[image]

For a single loop I can do patiently adjust its coordinate and arc on the corner. But with so many loops of different orientations and connections in the figure, I do not know an efficient way of producing it using tikz.

Do you guys know any package that can handle the connections of these loops?

Thanks.

Edit:
@cfr, thanks for your suggestion. The knot package seems to deal with the case that strands go under/above each other, for example

[image]

(picture from [this blog post](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/how-can-i-draw-a-knot-in-tex-let-me-count-the-ways/))

Instead, I need to draw sort of the self avoiding paths.

Comment: Maybe you could look at the code for one of the packages which uses TikZ to draw knots? That has to do something not dissimilar, I think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My answer consists of three parts.

## Step 1: decorate segments

First, we would like to replace every segment

[image]

by a *dumbbell*:

[image]

This could be done, as the title suggests, by defining a decoration and applying it. So we may write

```
\pgfdeclaredecoration{dumbbells}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=0pt,next state=depict one]{
    \egroup
    % set up parameters
    \bgroup
  }
  \state{depict one}[width=1cm,next state=depict one]
  {
    % construct the contour of the dumbbell
  }
  \state{final}{}
}
```

The size of dumbbells is controlled by `segment length`. For example

```
\tikz\draw[decorate,decoration={dumbbells,segment length=1cm}](0,0)--(1,0);
```

## Step 2: decoration options

We need the corner rounded

[image]

This is easy, we could use `rounded corners` in constructing the decoration.

We also need a *fat dumbbells*

[image]

Notice that the radius of corners vary. This is hard in Ti*k*Z. But in PGF, the radius is changed on each call of `\pgfsetcornersarced`.

The radius and the fatness are controlled by `rounded corners` and `border width`. For example

```
\tikz\draw[decorate,decoration={dumbbells,segment length=1cm,rounded corners=.2cm}](0,0)--(1,0);
\tikz\draw[decorate,decoration={dumbbells,segment length=1cm,rounded corners=.2cm,border width=.1cm}](0,0)--(1,0);
```

## Step 3: accumulating decorations

We need to draw a black, fat dumbbells. And then overlay it by a white, thin one. And then draw the dashes.

```
\tikzset{
    fill dumbbells/.style 2 args={
        decorate,decoration={
            dumbbells,
            segment length=1cm,
            rounded corners=.2cm,
            border width=#1,
            fill=#2
        }
    },
    draw dumbbells/.style={
        preaction={
            preaction={fill dumbbells={.01cm}{black}},
            postaction={fill dumbbells={-.01cm}{white}}
        },
        draw,dashed
    }
}
```

So now we can write

```
\tikz\draw[draw dumbbells](0,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2)--++(4,0)(2,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2);
```

[image]

## Full code

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\begin{document}

\newdimen\pgfdecorationcornersradius\newdimen\pgfdecorationborderwidth
\newdimen\a\newdimen\b\newdimen\o\newdimen\R\newdimen\r
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/decoration/.cd,
  rounded corners/.code={\pgfmathsetlength\pgfdecorationcornersradius{#1}},
  border width/.code={\pgfmathsetlength\pgfdecorationborderwidth{#1}},
  fill/.initial=black
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{dumbbells}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=0,next state=depict one]{
    \egroup
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/fill}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\a{.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}
    \pgfmathsetlength\b{1.41421\pgfdecorationborderwidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength\R{\pgfdecorationcornersradius+\pgfdecorationborderwidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength\r{\pgfdecorationcornersradius-\pgfdecorationborderwidth}
    \bgroup
  }
  \state{depict one}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=depict one]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\o}{\a+\b}}
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{\r}{\r}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\a}{\b}}
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{\R}{\R}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2\a}{\a+\b}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3\a+\b}{\o}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2\a}{-\a-\b}}
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{\r}{\r}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\a}{-\b}}
    \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{\R}{\R}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\o}{-\a-\b}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\a-\b}{\o}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }
  \state{final}{}
}

\tikz{
    \draw[decorate,decoration={dumbbells,segment length=1cm,fill=white}](0,0)--(1,0);
    \draw(0,0)--(1,0);
}
\tikz\draw[decorate,decoration={dumbbells,segment length=1cm}](0,0)--(1,0);
\tikz\draw[decorate,decoration={dumbbells,segment length=1cm,rounded corners=.2cm}](0,0)--(1,0);
\tikz\draw[decorate,decoration={dumbbells,segment length=1cm,rounded corners=.2cm,border width=.1cm}](0,0)--(1,0);

\tikzset{
    fill dumbbells/.style 2 args={
        decorate,decoration={
            dumbbells,
            segment length=1cm,
            rounded corners=.2cm,
            border width=#1,
            fill=#2
        }
    },
    draw dumbbells/.style={
        preaction={
            preaction={fill dumbbells={.01cm}{black}},
            postaction={fill dumbbells={-.01cm}{white}}
        },
        draw,dashed
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw dumbbells](0,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2)--++(4,0)(2,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6}{
        \foreach \y in {0,...,4}{
            \fill[black](\x,\y)circle(0.08/1.5);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Update

OP wants to "fill" empty nodes by isolated rhombus. The most easy way uses only Ti*k*Z's features `\foreach`, `rounded corners`, and `line width`.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6}{
        \foreach \y in {0,...,4}{
            \draw[rounded corners=.2cm,line width=.02cm](\x,\y)+(.5,0)--+(0,.5)--+(-.5,0)--+(0,-.5)--cycle;
        }
    }
    \draw[draw dumbbells](0,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2)--++(4,0)(2,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,2);
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6}{
        \foreach \y in {0,...,4}{
            \fill[black](\x,\y)circle(0.08/1.5);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Cool, but all the remaining nodes should have the romboidal edges, no?

Comment: @Alenanno I am sorry, but "rhomboidal edges"?

Comment: Oops sorry, I'm on the phone.  Yeah, I mean the other edges for the isolated nodes as the image in the op. .

Comment: @Alenanno I knew someone will ask about it. Well, one can do this by node shape, pic, marking, etc. But for decoration, it is hard to concentrate on isolated points.

Comment: @Alenanno, fantastic solution! I'm trying to modify your definition of dumbbells to draw a rhombus on isolated points, but the rhombus comes with a line. And I don't know how to accomplish this using node shape either. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: @anecdote Why are you tagging? The solution is not mine. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have tagged @Symbol1 ...